Pay session and payment card information capture
Update: After 2 weeks of communicating with Twilio support, it turns out there was an issue on their side and there was actually nothing wrong with what I was doing.
I'm in the process of implementing Pay Sessions using Payment Resources and I'm having issues with collecting information.
From what I understand from the docs (which is not all that clear), when I update a Pay Session passing the "Capture" parameter with the information I want to collect, it should trigger the collection on the call, right?
Currently everything goes well, I'm not getting any sort of errors from Twilio, but nothing happens when I update the Pay Session.
I'm doing this in PHP, here is basically my code:
I initiate the Pay Session as in the docs:
$sid = getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
$token = getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$twilio
    ->calls("MyCallSid")
    ->payments->create(
        "abcde",
        "https://www.mycallbackurl.com"
    );

This works fine, my pay session is initialized and I'm able to cancel it as well.
How I try to trigger information collection by updating the resource:
$twilio
    ->calls("MyCallSid")
    ->payments("MyPaySessionId")
    ->update(
        "asdfqwer",
        "https://www.mycallbackurl.com",
        ["capture" => "payment-card-number"]
    );

While this technically runs without any errors, nothing happens on the call, and the callback URL is never called by Twilio.
From my understanding of the (unclear) docs, this should trigger the payment card number collection, so I expect some sort of generic instructions to be played on the call for the callee (voice prompt), or isn't this what this does?
The documentation really needs clarification on payment resources.

"generic instructions", "played" - what are you talking about here, with those weird terms/phrases?

@C3roe We are talking about collecting payment card information, if I'm triggering collection for the payment card number, I expect Twilio to trigger vocal instructions for the callee, but again, the docs is not clear about what is supposed to happen next, do I have to use a  verb myself?

@DarkBee Yes I'm certain, the callback URL is never called, I can see all the requests coming in using Laravel Telescope.
